# Create new branch and move uncommitted working copy changes to it using SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

In git, I would typically do something like:

```
git checkout -b my-new-branch-name
```

, and this would copy all my uncommitted working copy changes into the new branch `my-new-branch-name` and move the head to that new branch.

How would I do the same in SVN?  I know SVN has lots of commands that are same as git, for example `svn status` is equivalent to `git status`.  Or `svn diff` is same as `git diff`, but doing

```
svn checkout -b my-new-branch-name
```

wont work.

Comment: Don't rely on similar terminology. In particular, "checkout" means different things in Git and Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

From the working copy where your local changes lie:

1. Create the branch with the **TortoiseSVN/ Branch/tag…** context menu. Make sure (and this is important) to use the repository version as source:

   [image: Create copy in the repository from]

   Also, click the **Switch working copy to new branch/tag** checkbox so
   TortoiseSVN will automatically switch your working copy to the new
   branch. If you forget to do so, just issue a **TortoiseSVN/ Switch…** command
   afterwards.
2. Commit your local changes as usual.